# When casting a derived class to a parent class do you lose data?

Tags: java

For example

```
public class parentClass{
     //stuff done
 }

public class derivedClass extends parentClass{
    // has data that parentClass does not
}

// some function 
public parentClass foo(parentClass myVar){
    return myVar
}

// ... later ...

{
  ...
   derivedClass dClass1 = new derivedClass();

   parentClass pClass = foo(dClass1);

   derivedClass dClass2 = (derivedClass)pClass;
 ...
}
```

Was data lost between dClass1 and dClass2? I am not sure, I think the answer is no. I know that if I was using doubles and ints then data IS lost, but that isn't using pointers and objects, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: No.  You lose access to the data, simply because the program doesn't "know about" it, but once cast back to the correct subclass you can access the data again.

Comment: (Casting is overloaded 3 ways in Java -- "scalars", object references, and "boxing".  They are all three completely different concepts, divided by a common notation.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant cast objects so you can't lose data. All you can do is cast the *reference* to an object and this doesn't alter it in any way.

Comment: So in my example are dClass1, dClass2 and pClass all references to the same object?

Comment: Yes. You can check this by printing dClass1 == pClass

Comment: Makes sense, I thought that was probably how it worked but I thought it might be possible that "casting" created a new object. Thanks!

Comment: If you pass an object to a copy constructor it will convert it to a new object or type.